# How to apply background color formatting

Tags: colors, background

I am trying to figure out how to apply background color based on a cell >5 to be orange in a column titled value. I currently have a template in google sheets with the following to format the column which works fine but I cannot figure out the background coloring (column 12 is titled value)

```
tbody>tr>:nth-child(2){
 color:red;
 width:200px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be much easier for someone to help you out if you post a minimal snippet of your HTML as well. to illustrate what you're trying to select

Comment: I am not sure what is needed - i have created a table in awesome table that is using the data from google sheets. I have a template in google sheet to apply the <style> code listed above so cell a1 has <style> and a2 has the above code. So basically I would like the specified column (2) that has a heade called value to show numbers greater than 5 with a tellow background